# Swift Reference Cycle When Capturing A Computed String Property Declared From Inside An Instance Method

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, computed-properties

I'm implementing an in-game store using Swift and SpriteKit. There is a class called `Store` which has a method `setupItems()` inside of which we declare and instantiate instances of a class `StoreItem` and also add each store item instance as a child of `Store`. Each `StoreItem` has an optional closure property called `updateInventory` which is set inside of `setupItems()` as well. This is an optional closure because some items don't have a limited inventory.

`Store` also has an `unowned` instance property `storeDelegate` which is responsible for determining how funds are deducted and how `storeItems` are applied once purchased. `storeDelegate` is `unowned` as it has an equal or greater lifetime than `Store`.

Now, here is where things get interesting - the closure `updateInventory` references a computed string variable called `itemText` which makes a calculation based on a property of `storeDelegate`. If `itemText` is declared and instantiated as a variable inside of `setupItems()` we have a reference cycle and store is not deallocated. If instead, `itemText` is declared and instantiated as an instance property of `Store` (right under the property `unowned storeDelegate` that it references) then there is no reference cycle and everything deallocates when it should.

This seems to imply that referencing `storeDelegate` from a computed variable inside an instance method of a class doesn't respect the `unowned` qualifier. Code examples follow:

***Current Scenario***

```
protocol StoreDelegate: AnyObject {
    func subtractFunds(byValue value: Int)
    func addInventoryItem(item: InventoryItem) throws
    var player: Player! { get }
}

class Store: SKSpriteNode, StoreItemDelegate {
    unowned var storeDelegate: StoreDelegate
    
    init(storeDelegate: StoreDelegate) {
        self.storeDelegate = storeDelegate
        setupItems()
        ...
    }
    func setupItems() {
        var itemText: String { 
            return "item info goes here \(storeDelegate.player.health)"
        }
        
        let storeItem = StoreItem(name: "coolItem")
        storeItem.updateInventory = {
            [unowned storeItem, unowned self] in
            // some logic to check if the update is valid
            guard self.storeDelegate.player.canUpdate() else {
                return
            }
            storeItem.label.text = itemText
        }

    }
```

The above leads to a reference cycle, interestingly if we move

```
var itemText: String { 
    return "item info goes here \(storeDelegate.player.health)"
}
```

outside of `updateItems` and make it an instance variable of `Store` right below `unowned var storeDelegate: StoreDelegate`, then there is no reference cycle.

I have no idea why this would be the case and don't see mention of it in the docs. Any suggestions would be appreciated and let me know if you'd like any additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`storeItem.updateInventory` now keeps strong reference to `itemText`.

I think the issue is that `itemText` holds a strong reference to `self` implicitly in order to access `storeDelegate`, instead of keeping a reference to `storeDelegate`. Anothe option is that even though `self` is keeping the delegate as `unowned`, once you pass ot to `itemText` for keeping, it is managed (ie, strong reference again).

Either way, you can guarantee not keeping strong reference changing `itemText` to a function and pass the delegate directly:

```
func setupItems() {
  func itemText(with delegate: StoreDelegate) -> String
    return "item info goes here \(storeDelegate.player.health)"
  }
  let storeItem...
  storeItem.updateInventory = {
    // ...
    storeItem.label.text = itemText(with self.storeDelegate)
   }
 }
```

Comment: but does this explain why moving `itemText` from inside `setupItems` to the top of `Store` as an instance var resolves the reference cycle?

Comment: Yes - if you move it outside you are now only holding unowned self inside updateInventory, but not the function itemText

Comment: I mean to ask why moving `itemText` (the computed property) to the top of `Store` as an instance var rather than a var inside `setupItems` resolves the ref cycle - I'm not referring to the function you suggest (although this is good idea in general)

Comment: Yes I understand - with your code using a `var` computed property, when calling `storeItem.label.text = itemText` it keeps a strong reference to that computed property, which itself is holding a strong reference to `self`. Once you move `itemText` to be an instance var, then the call `storeItem.label.text = itemText` passes through the `unowned self` - meaning, your `updateInventory` isn't holding `itemText` anymore, but only the `unowned self`...